# NuGet and .NET Target Framework

Tags: .net, nuget

I recently changed the target framework from `.NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile` to `.NET Framework 4.0`.

Can I still keep on using the `NuGet` packages that specify `targetFramework="net40-Client"`? Under packages.congig for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
   <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net40-Client" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Did you try? Does it compile? Does it complain?

Comment: It doesn't complain. I'd just like to know if there's any difference/benefit of making all packages to use "net40"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.
The 4.0 Client Profile is a subset of the full 4.0 framework, and Client Profile libraries can be consumed by full framework assemblies.